# Elif giving invalid syntax python?

Tags: python

This is the code i have been using but it is not working as it says that the elif statement is invalid syntax. Can anyone help me because i am a beginner in python.

```
age = int(input('How old are you?: '))
if age <= 16:
    print ('You are too young to enter this section of the program!')
else:
    age >= 16
    print ('Welcome to the advanced section of the program!')

elif: password = int(input('please enter the password to enter the elite members section: ')):
    if password == ('muffin'):
        print ('Well done for unlocking the secret part of the program')
    else:
            print ('You shall not pass!')
```

Comment: the elif should always be before the else and should have its own boolean statement

Comment: Others have pointed out your misuse of if, elif, else. But another thing I notice is that it seems your **intended** usage of if and else would serve here to exhaust all values of age (ok, maybe not NaNs), having a third conditional serves no purpose. Also, your if and else would both be true if age == 16

Answer (score 6):

`elif` needs a condition (ie `elif 7 > 5:` ....) also an `elif` cannot follow an `else` and **must** follow an `if` or `elif` condition

in your case your `elif` has no condition ,so python does not know what to do

your `elif` also follows your `else` Im not sure what you actually expect it to do ...

Answer (score 1):

Your `elif` has no conditional. Else if...*what*?

```
else:
    age >= 16
```

This *looks* like an attempt at an `elif`. Should this really be

```
elif age >= 16:
```

That'd make sense based on your `if`.

Additionally, `elif` goes before `else`. If you are using `elif`, it needs to occur after the `if` but before the `else`:

```
if ...
elif ...
else ...
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, be sure to have a condition for your `elif` statement as well as place it between your `if` and `else`.  You may also run into an issue with your statements when a user's age is 16 as both your `if` and `else` technically qualify at this point.